# Conflicting System.Web.Http.Cors assembly in azure mobile services

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

Suddenly I got the following error when publishing to Azure Mobile Services.

"Error  Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly 'System.Web.Http.Cors': 5.1.0.0, 5.2.2.0. Please change your project to use only one version. App.Hosting 2014-09-20 23:40:26"

I use Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors and WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Backend (1.0.348).

I have tried going through all references and I cant find any pointing at 5.2.2.0.
I have also tried upgrading to 5.2.2.0 however when doing so I get:
"Error  Boot strapping failed: executing 'WebApiConfig.Register' caused an exception: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http.Cors, Version=5.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'.   App.Hosting 2014-09-20 23:06:20"

I can not understand why I get this error and it seem to have start to occur with no apparent reason.

Any pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are in the process of updating to the newly released ASP.NET Web API 5.2 and it looks like we missed an assembly redirect for the CORS assembly.

In a couple of days you will be able to use the full ASP.NET Web API 5.2 but the upgrade has to complete first. To fix your problem now, you should be able to just remove your own CORS assembly (assuming you are only setting the origins) and then set them using the MS_CrossDomainOrigins app setting in your local web.config as described in this blog [1], for example:

```
<add key="MS_CrossDomainOrigins" value="http://testhost, http://sample" />
```

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Henrik

[1] http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/28/azure-mobile-services-net-updates/

Comment: Hi Henrik and thank you for your answer!

I use the EnableCors attribute on my controllers and specify http methods. I guess this will not work then until the update is completed?

Will there be any announcement once the update is completed?  

My app is (now) only in development and it runs under my MSDN subscription. However would this update have inflicted my app if it had been running in production? If so what can I do (in a production scenario) to circumvent this kind of issue in the future? (Have there been an announcement about this update that I might have missed?)

Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, we will blog about it and I'll tweet about it at @frystyk 
I apologize for the problems. One question I have though -- even though you get the frowny, I wonder whether your CORS settings don't actually still work? That's at least what I see. 

thanks!

Comment: Hi again, Henrik! I tried to access my service despite the frown. Doing so I first got an error telling me "Boot strapping failed: executing 'WebApiConfig.Register' caused an exception: 'Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service.ConfigOptions.set_CorsPolicy". So i thought that the API might have changed in 5.2 and commented out the setting of the CORS policy in the Register method. Although that left me with this Information instead "Message='No CorsPolicyProvider selected'" which in turn seem to make the OPTIONS request return a 405 (Method Not Allowed). Thanks again!

Comment: We are about to deploy a fix and would love to see if you could please confirm that it fixes your issue. Would you mind sending me the name of your service to henrikn AT microsoft.com?

Thanks again for your help!

Henrik